# Undefined reference to (Quickmail)

Tags: c, windows, email, mingw

I am looking for how to install quickmail.

I put `quickmail.h` here: `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include`, the `.a` and `.la` here: `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib`.

I linked these `.a` files by adding them in the linker settings. I also did include the library like this: `#include <quickmail.h>`, but the functions are not recognized.

What should I do ?

The 4 files in the bin folder are in the project folder and I downloaded files from here : [quickmail - Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/).

EDIT : I get `\main.c|9|undefined reference to '__imp_quickmail_initialize'| \main.c|10|undefined reference to '__imp_quickmail_create'| \main.c|11|undefined reference to '__imp_quickmail_set_body'` and I put `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include` in search directories.

This is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <quickmail.h>

int main()
{
    const char* error;

    quickmail_initialize();
    quickmail mailobj = quickmail_create("aaa@gmail.com", "libquickmail test e-mail");
    quickmail_set_body(mailobj, "This is a test e-mail.\nThis mail was sent using libquickmail.");
    quickmail_add_attachment_file(mailobj, "words.txt", NULL);

    if ((error = quickmail_send(mailobj, "smtp.gmail.com", 587, "aaa@gmail.com", "MAGA2020")) != NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending e-mail: %s\n", error);

    quickmail_destroy(mailobj);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry, the site gave me the wrong version.

Comment: you need to tell the linker too - how did you compile and link? COmmand line or in an IDE

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: The line `#include <quickmail.h>` includes a header, not a library.  Headers are text files; libraries are collections of object files.

Comment: I compiled and linked  in code blocks, not with command line.

Comment: I put `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include` in search directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a library you need to include the header in the code (in this case `#include <quickmail.h>`) and if needed tell the compiler where to find this file (the full path to the `lib` folder) with the `-I` compiler flag.

Next you need to tell the linker to link with the library (in this case `-lquickmail` or `-lquickmaillight`) and if needed where to find this file (the full path to the `lib` folder) with the `-L` linker flag.

Your errors are linker errors, so it seems the second step wasn't properly done.

In Code::Blocks it looks like this (though unlike the screenshots you should set it at the top-level instead of just for Debug builds):
[image]
[image]
[image]